# CentOS 7 - wait with login until script is running

Tags: centos, login, service

Is there a method to delay the login for the user on CentOS 7 Minimal until a specific service is running?

I've created a service for it, so it runs right after install via kickstart and it works like a charm. However after the install the root can login while the script is running and since there is a reboot command in the script if the root logs in, suddently he get's dropped out because the server restarts. How can I prevent a login until the service is running?

Cheers!

Bert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't lock out `root` during this, but rather put a message into `/etc/motd` to warn that an install process is running. Just before the `reboot` command, you can remove the message again.

To prevent a regular user from login during this, `echo` a message into `/etc/nologin`. That file should be removed automatically on reboot.